# Improve efficiency of MySQL self-join statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table of tuples and need to know if the row contains a root or leaf using 2 SQL statements.

The SQL statements work but are extremely slow (each statement takes ~6 hours for a 100k row table on a dedicated RHEL web server) so I'd like to get some ideas on how to improve performance.

For the decision-making -> Root meaning where 'parent' value is not found in any table row in 'child' and Leaf meaning where 'child' value is not found in any table row in 'parent'.

Table 'tuples'...

```
parent   varchar(20),
child    varchar(20),
root     boolean,
leaf     boolean
```

Table is indexed on unique parent+child.

The table is set up to have default values for root & leaf of true.

The 1st SQL statement finds rows which are not a root and the 2nd finds rows which are not a leaf.

```
update tuples t1 inner join tuples t2 on (t1.parent in (select t2.child)) set t1.root=false;

update tuples t1 inner join tuples t2 on (t1.child in (select t2.parent)) set t1.leaf=false;
```

=> Does anyone have a better (faster) statement than I have been able to find up to now?
Thanks.

Comment: When you say that the "*table is indexed on unique parent+child*", one presumes you mean that you have a `UNIQUE` index over the composite of both columns?  Have you also defined another index which is prefixed by the second column from that `UNIQUE` index?  Also, your join criteria can (and *should*) be expressed as `t1.parent=t2.child` etc, rather than `in (select ..))` which could well be materialising unindexed intermediary tables (depends on MySQL version—you'd need to check the execution plan using `EXPLAIN` to see for certain).

Comment: @eggyal Yes, the table has a unique index on the composite of parent and child.Your indexing suggestion is to have a 2nd composite index on child and parent? I'll try a change to t1.parent=t2.child - Thanks.

Comment: No need for a second composite on child and parent—an index on child alone should suffice (provided the order of the columns in the original index was parent first, child second).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to replace the first update query:

```
UPDATE tuples t1
    LEFT JOIN tuples t2 on t2.child=t1.parent
SET t1.root=0
WHERE t2.parent is NULL
```

Correlated subqueries can be quite slow.  I like to replace them with JOINs where possible.  If that works for you, a similar approach can recast the second update query as well.

Comment: Jim, thanks also for your suggestion. This is part of a batch job and last night I had a total rethink and rewrote the code in a PHP script so I could do row-at-a-time processing, first fetching the whole table and then for each row counting hits on parent and child and updating one row at a time. Working this way, the batch last night finished in approx 6.5 minutes compared to the previous version of purely SQL needing 12 hours.

Comment: I am betting the recast SQL will beat PHP !